# To what is this capacitor connected? (OP-amp)

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor

[image: OP-amp with capacitor]

I'm a little bit confused. Is the capacitor in parallel with Vs+?

Comment: What is the part number of the opamp? Some op-amps require a capacitor connected externally for stability. They have extra pins for that.  An example of such a opamp would be the Apex PA95.

Comment: It's an LM741 OP-amp.

Comment: The schematic might be representing the (internal) capacitor of a '741 op amp, and not be intended at all to represent external wiring to an external capacitor.

Comment: CA3130 needed a cap like that except when used a a comparator.

Answer (score 2):

Usually external compensation is a series R-C. Some very old op-amps (eg. [LM709](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm709.pdf)) had separate input and output compensation.

[image]

For an LM741 maybe they are putting a capacitor across the offset null terminals. I can't say as I've seen that recommended before. Or maybe the schematic was originally drawn for another kind of op-amp that required external compensation.